# Low maxGCPauseMillis and high initial heap size causing high number of young GCs

Tags: java, jvm

We have our `maxGCPauseMillis` as 100, and we were seeing high number of young GCs. After increasing the initial heap size to 1 GB, which was the default value earlier (~60MB), the number of such high young GC cases increased.

I could not understand why increasing the initial heap size might cause that issue to worsen. Any pointers anyone has to what might be happening here?

GC args before the change:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1048576 -XX:InitialHeapSize=60817408 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:MaxHeapSize=968884224 
-XX:MaxNewSize=580911104 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=1048576 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseFastUnorderedTimeStamps 
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

GC args after the change:

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:InitialHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

Here are some gc logs pastes:

- https://pastebin.com/HyxX3HTJ
- https://pastebin.com/ZkcaqHhS
- https://pastebin.com/5HP5HznS

Comment: Increasing heap size can also affect other default settings, print them with `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and diff the results. A likely candidate is young generation size.

Comment: @Holger I had checked the gc logs, and `-XX:InitialHeapSize=60817408` was present, and after the change it was `968884224`, so I do think it was changed.

Comment: @Holger I will add the before / after gc args in the question, in some time. I think that should help people with actual data, and would be useful

Comment: Hey @Holger, have added the JVM args and GC details

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. What actual numbers are the “high number of young GCs”? What actual pause times do you get; does the GC meat your max time goal or does it sometimes fail?

Comment: Here are some gc logs pastes:
https://pastebin.com/HyxX3HTJ, https://pastebin.com/ZkcaqHhS, https://pastebin.com/5HP5HznS. Basically I am seeing a 5-6 GCs per second.

Comment: Before or after the change? It isn’t a bad number. Mind that the purpose of a concurrent GC is to minimize the pause lengths, not the number of pauses.

Comment: @Holger Ohkay - So these numbers are not abnormal. Just one more question -  do you see any issues with the `maxGCPauseMillis` value of 100ms?  I've read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) and [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsConfigG1Gc.html), that it's value shouldn't be too less, or it will cause GC bursts. Any pointers on that you can share?

Comment: A value of 100ms is not unusual, but of course, it depends on the application. You’ll have to monitor your application to see, whether you’re seeing the total amount of used memory to pile up over time, until a full gc kicks in to get rid of it. If you see no such process, it’s fine.

Answer (score -1):

maxGCPauseMillis is related to GC pause during FullGC not relate to young GC or frequency of young GC.
Which GC policy you are using & what are the other GC & heap parameters?